# 2D animations in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, directx, unity-game-engine

I would like to develop a Tamagotchi game for Windows Phone 8 and I don't know how to do it.

My problem is that I don't know if I need to use Directx 3D or XAML, because I'm going to show a 2D pet moving around the screen.

I've thought to use 2D sprites to show its movement and let the user to stroke it.

Do I have to use Direct3D? Unity? What do you recommend me?

Comment: Unity supports WP8 - http://unity3d.com/pages/windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use XAML for a game. If you're going to be doing animations and complex interactions, that would be a nightmare. You can, however, use it for your game menus and layouts. Check out this tutorial on [XAML and Direct3D apps for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207012%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Unity doesn't automatically make the game 3D, you can create 2D games with it. XNA is being phased out, so I suggest you stay away from that. Go with Unity for your engine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to add a menu with actions: to feed it, select the food (hamburguer, bread...). Can I add such kind of menu and buttons using Unity?

Comment: @VansFannel yup, those will just be buttons on screen whose function is to launch that menu. However, take note that you'll have to draw up all those menus from scratch. If you use XAML, you'll have built-in controls, but they may not match the art theme of your game, since it'll still have that Windows Phone "flavor" :)

Comment: 'draw up all those menus from scratch'? Do I have to use Unity to design those menus and buttons?

Comment: MonoGame is an open source replacement for XNA.

Comment: @VansFannel You could create the graphics beforehand, and have them drawn as "touchable" images using Unity